# Kafka-Strams purge GlobalKTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

in my kafka-streams topology i have only one a GlobalKTable from one topic AYZ:

```
streamsBuilder.globalTable(
                "AYZ",
                Consumed.with(getKeySerde(), getValueSerde())
                        .withName("Source-in"),
                createMaterializedView());
```

Next, I want to delete all GlobalKTable entries older than two hours, because there will be a lot of entries.

I already tried to use ProzessorSupplier, which takes a name of my lokal store and deletes required entries:

```
KStream<MessageKey, DistilledMessage> inStream = streamsBuilder.stream(
                "AYZ",Consumed.with(getKeySerde(), getValueSerde()));

inStream.process(() -> new MyHouseKeeper(), Named.as("houseKeeper"), "MyStore")
```

But i can not use two sources (glabalKTable, stream) from one topic.
I get error:

> Topic AYZ has already been registered by another source.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you cannot use async on head because it is usually using some static values.

And looking at this github answer, it looks like you can use asyncData to have access to the values you want to input in head.

Comment: What are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to understand how to answer better. You seem to refer to some github answer? (repo/issue perhaps?), but haven't included any links to it that OP can check.